# What version of Clips should I use - Clips 6.4Beta or 6.31?

Tags: rule-engine, clips, expert-system

What version of Clips should I use - Clips 6.4Beta or 6.31? Are there any problems with the Beta version?

Comment: CLIPS 6.4 has been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either. Version 6.4 Beta is stable, I've just been slow in packaging the final release version. If you're embedding CLIPS within another program, you'll want to use 6.4 as the APIs have been redesigned. The 6.4 Windows IDE now supports unicode, so you'll want to use that if your program needs to display unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

**CLIPS - Tool for Development and Delivery of Rule Based Expert Systems**

> CLIPS is free to NASA, USAF, and their contractors for use on NASA and
> USAF projects

I find [Gary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232642/gary-riley)'s website really useful for this & many other CLIPS answers:
[CLIPSrules.net](http://CLIPSrules.net)

Especially the USER GUIDE in HTML which can be found here: http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v624/ug.htm

Would love to see more on Github nowadays:
[https://github.com/search?q=C+Language+Integrated+Production+System](https://github.com/search?q=C%20Language%20Integrated%20Production%20System)

https://github.com/topics/clips?l=clips

The more recent Python rules engine / recommendation engine / Expert System CLIPS library is here:
https://github.com/noxdafox/clipspy

or search the web for useful Tutorials:
https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/clips/tutorial

> a rule is expressed in the form **IF** something is true
> **THEN** do some action.
> This kind of rule is known as a production.
> For this reason, rule-based expert systems are often known as **production systems**
> (CLIPS actually stands for *C Language Integrated Production System*).
> In CLIPS, a typical rule looks like this:

```
(defrule is-it-a-duck
  (animal-has webbed-feet)          ; IF
  (animal-has feathers)             ; AND
  =>                                ; THEN
  (assert (animal-is duck)))
```

Thanks to [Gary Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232642/gary-riley) for maintaining [CLIPS rules](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules) !

[clips] [Expert-System] [Rules-Engine] [Recommendation-Engine]  [Python] [cffi]